# How to pass URL parameter to Controller's Action

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following route:

```
Route::get('reviewers/{id}', 'ReviewerController@single');
```

and have this action on my ReviewerController:

```
public function single(){
$id = Input::get('id');
return View::make('reviewer.single')
->with('id', $id);}
```

In my single View, I dumped the value of $id and it is NULL. Although I did supplied an id in the url(e.g., reviewers/1) why is the $id null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
public function single($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id; // if you haven't already ensured it's integer with Route::pattern() method
    return View::make('reviewer.single')->with('id', $id);
}
```

To use route wildcards and pass the data, controller methods must have the necessary parameters. Input facade isn't used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the url you would generate it like *reviewers/2*. Laravel has several [helper](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers) methods to generate urls to routes, for example to a named route or:

```
//route to controller action
$url = action('ReviewerController@single', $id);
```

In your controller:

```
public function single($id){
    return View::make('reviewer.single')
      ->with('id', $id);
}
```